# How to send raw emails with swiftmailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I can't seem to find a way to be able to send a completely raw email with swiftmailer in php (or with any emailer to be honest).

By completely raw I mean the email itself is the actual string already encoded with header, body, attachment etc already in it.

I don't need to or want to construct the message with `->addTo()` and such, I have the complete email string, just needs to be sent.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: hi, it might help [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632399/given-an-email-as-raw-text-how-can-i-send-it-using-php)

Comment: well, it only helps in a sense that I can see noone could really answer that. The reason I wanted to use a proper mailer component because I dont want to deal with tls, authentication, etc on a socket level...